# Cant Build my App in Release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing

My App works fine in debug mode, but if i want to build it in release i get the following error:

```
Fehler  1   Unerwarteter Fehler bei der LinkAssemblies-Aufgabe.
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Element::set_AutomationId(System.String)' (defined in assembly 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms, Version=2.1.47.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Element::set_AutomationId(System.String)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   bei Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   bei MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()    Euroscola_App1
```

This problem exists since today, i dont know if the reason is that i downloaded a newer Xamarin version or because i have installed the ZXing Package.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you remove ZXing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded.

You have the application Linker enabled in your `Xamarin.Android` application project and there is a mismatch in versions between forwarded types in `Xamarin.Forms` and `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms`. Basically `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` was compiled against an older version of Forms then you currently are using in your project and is a really common issue if the assembly contains C# extensions.

Two options, disable linking for the entire application or disable linking for just the Zing assembly:

To disable linking for just that one assembly, edit your Android application project (`.csproj`) and add the following `< AndroidLinkSkip>`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidLinkSkip>ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms</AndroidLinkSkip>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Ref: Xamarin Android Linking: [`AndroidLinkSkip`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)

Comment: I had a similar problem the offending library was `Rg.Plugins.Popup` and the library that had issues (couldnt resolve) was `System.Collections.Generic.Queue`. I tried the link skip on `Rg.Plugins.Popup` but still go the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @G_Money here is solution for ur question https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/540